# Converting date from one timezone to another when both date types are DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I regularly seem to have to work with converting a DateTimeOffset value to another timezone also in DateTimeOffset. the big headache has been the fact that the TimeZoneInfo class convert method returns DateTime, so I end up having to convert the data again when I it to a DateTimeOffset type.

To over come this, I cam up with an extension method for the DateTimeOffset:

*This has to exist in a class.*

```
public static DateTimeOffset ToNewTimeZone(this DateTimeOffset value, string timeZone)
{
    value = value.UtcDateTime;
    TimeZoneInfo tzObject = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
    //Using the GetUtcOffset means that the TimeZoneInfo class is responsible for calculating the Daylight savings time.
    DateTimeOffset ret = value.ToOffset(tzObject.GetUtcOffset(value));
    return ret;
}
```

It works extremely well under every test case I have come up with, but it seems inelegant to me. Which is usually a sign that there is already a better solution. However I have yet to find one.

I create a .NET Fiddle to show my work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/LLl1Za

Lines 42 and 43 highlight this code in light of my other experiments above it.

Just so that we have context, I cannot change the DB to store data in UTC only, and just change the zone for the client screens. The project is too big and expansive to make this change now. There a many articles that talk about other timezone handling issues, but just not this specific scenario.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The above code won't compile.  What did you mean by `DateTimeOffset ret = ret.ToOffset(tzObject.GetUtcOffset(value));`?

Comment: Go to the https://dotnetfiddle.net/LLl1Za and look at lines 42 and 43. you will see exactly how that works. I don't have it wrapped in a function, but I have it working there.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MonroeThomas So 'tzObject' when you use 'GetUtcOffset' will grab the right offset including Daylight savings time rules. So when you kick in the 'ToOffset', you are changing the time to the new offset.

Comment: Leaving this embarrassing question up, because I should know better than using Bing, As for Google results, I have no clue as to why I got better results now unless I had an ugly typo. Also I want to make sure people get credit for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you should implement it yourself. You should use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` to change the timezone of a `DateTimeOffset`.

Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I did it myself because no matter how many times I Googled or Binged the answer the top 3 pages were everything except this. And VS wasn't showing me 2 more overrides to the convert, just DateTime. Glad I asked.

Comment: I just Googled once: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=datetimeoffset%20change%20timezone